# 25x10mm 5V fan is too loud

Tags: fan, acoustic-noise

I'm using a 25x10mm fan ([Sunon MF25100V1-1000U-A99](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/2315/MF25100V1-1000U-A99.pdf)) - I was using a different fan from the same manufacturer ([Sunon MC25060V2-000U-A99](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/sunon-fans/MC25060V2-000U-A99/2757803?s=N4IgTCBcDaILIGEwFYAMA2VA1MBaVBAqrgIICcZIAugL5A)) and just plugging it right 5V/GND and it worked fine. Unfortunately that fan went obsolete / out-of-production, and I selected the other fan to replace it. I find that the new fan is much louder in the same electrical setup, to the point where I don't think it's tolerable for the end-users of my product.

So I'm doing some experimenting to try and solve this problem, and I decided to try PWM'ing the fan through a spare open/GND n-channel MOSFET which I happen to have on my board under software control. The circuit looks like this (using [DMN2004DMK-7](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds30937.pdf)):

[image]

I'm connecting the fan's red wire to 5V and the black wire to /DIN1 (aka pin D1), and PWM'ing the DIN1 signal (aka pin G1) in software with a 3.3V MCU output. For various settings of duty cycle and frequency, I can give up some airflow and drastically reduce the fan noise. It seems like the lower I set the frequency, the higher I can go in duty cycle to a similar effect, and in all cases of frequency, there's a single step in duty cycle (dependent on frequency) where the fan suddenly goes from being reasonably quiet to being loud.

I've settled (somewhat arbitrarily) on a PWM frequency of 18kHz and a duty cycle of 200 / 255 = ~78.5%. I'm not trying to implement variable fan speed control or anything like that, I just want a reasonably constant airflow through my enclosure and make the fan noise not be obnoxious. It seems like it's doing what I want.

Am I making a terrible mistake here? Any advice on whether my choice of frequency and duty cycle is a good one? Just looking for experience-based feedback on the mitigation strategy I'm attempting here.

Comment: Look at section V.I.7 of the datasheet.

Comment: @vir oof I missed that... any idea what the concern is there? Again I'm not 'controlling' the fan speed just 'reducing' it and I'm kinda stuck with this fan.

Comment: OK... so maybe I just run the fan off of 3.3V instead of 5V, result is similar to PWM

Comment: Probably the control electronics do not like being PWMed.

Comment: @vir if you want to create an answer, I would happily up-vote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note V.I.7 on page 11 of the datasheet says not to use PWM on either the ground or power terminal to control the fan speed - likely because of the internal drive/monitoring electronics. Your plan to supply a constant 3.3V to drive the fan should work, as it is inside the operating voltage range of 2.5-6V.  This of course does not preclude using the spare MOSFET to turn it on and off.

I would also measure the current draw at 3.3V and make sure that it is acceptable for the entire power path since the values on the datasheet may have been measured at 5V.